# Javascript hard-coded object works as parameter, but not reference to global object

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, flot

I'm running into an odd issue with JQuery Flot.

I had been running

```
var plot = null;

function initPlot () {
    plot = $.plot("#graph", myData, { /* my options here */ });
}
```

and everything worked fine.

I moved my options data into a variable within the scope of the function

```
var plot = null;

function initPlot () {
    var myOptions = { /* my options here */ };
    plot = $.plot("#graph", myData, myOptions);
}
```

and again, everything works fine.

Then I moved the variable to a broader scope (so I could reference it in other functions).

```
var plot = null;
var myOptions = { /* my options here */ };

function initPlot () {
    plot = $.plot("#graph", myData, myOptions);
}
```

Suddenly it won't plot correctly.  What's even more confusing to me is that it gets the values of most of the options--the graph appears, just not the data.

Using Chrome's debugger, I can see that `myOptions` has the correct value at the time I call `$.plot()`.  I also tried setting a local variable `o = myOptions` and calling `$.plot()` with `o` instead of `myOptions`, but this, too, fails to plot the data.

What's causing this and how do I fix it?

I should note that I'm using Flot.Grow and Flot.Stack, but disabling these does not change the result.

**EDIT (again)**

Per the comments, here is literally the state of my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="graph" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div>
    <script>
        var idMap = {};
        var yesData = [];
        var noData = [];
        var incData = [];
        var voteData = [{ label: "Yes votes", data: yesData },
                        { label: "No votes", data: noData },
                        { label: "Not met quorum", data: incData }];
        var ticks = [];
        var plot = null;

        var myOptions = {
            series: {
                //stack: true,
                lines: {
                    show: false,
                    fill: true,
                    steps: false,
                },
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: .8,
                    horizontal: true,
                },
                //grow: {
                //    active: false,
                //    steps: 20,
                //    stepDirection: "up",
                //    stepMode: "linear",
                //    valueIndex: 0,
                //    growings: [{
                //        valueIndex: 0,
                //    }]
                //},
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: -.2,
                max: 10, //dictLen(idMap),
                //ticks: ,
                //tickLength: 0,
            },
            xaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 200,
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
            },
        };

        function dictLen(obj) {
            var size = 0, key;
            for (key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
            }
            return size;
        };

        function setDataPoint(val) {
            var total = val.r["yes"] + val.r["no"];
            if (total < val.q) {
                incData.push([total, idMap[val.id]]);
            }
            else {
                yesData.push([val.r["yes"], idMap[val.id]]);
                noData.push([val.r["no"], idMap[val.id]]);
            }
        }

        function initData() {
            $.getJSON('/Vote/results', function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    idMap[val.id] = key;
                    ticks.push([key + .4, val.nm]);
                    setDataPoint(val);
                });

                initPlot();
            });
        }

        function initPlot() {
            plot = $.plot("#graph", voteData, myOptions);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            initData();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is `myData` initialized?

Comment: It may be that Flot is internally keeping a reference directly to that object. Maybe try `$.plot("#graph", data, $.extend({}, myOptions))`

Comment: @laruiss Up above, right before `myOptions` is.

Comment: When is `initPlot` called?

Comment: Well passing in a fresh copy of your object is exactly the same as passing in an object literal typed directly into the function call; the code on the receiving end can't tell the difference. Are you **sure** that that's the only relevant change to your code?

Comment: @DaveNewton `$(document).ready(function () { initData(); });`

`initData()` calls it at the end of a `$.getJSON()` call

Comment: Can you show more of the code surrounding this? It looks `myData` or `myOptions` is being changed somewhere.

Comment: @Pointy I know... that's why I'm confused.  And I'm sure that's the only change I made.  I tried several times, literally copying and pasting.  VS's reformat text shows that the scopes are right, so it's not a missing or extra brace.

Comment: `myOptions` is just a static object, nothing computed, etc? There's nothing else that gets filled in in any other way?

Comment: @DaveNewton It did have some computation, which I thought might have been the issue, but I set them to static values, and got the same result.

Comment: I edited the question, copying and pasting literally all of my script code.  (The rest is very minimal HTML.)

Comment: I figured out the issue.  It came from debugging two issues at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I'm a bit of an idiot.

The issue was that I was calculating `myOptions.yaxis.max` before `idMap` was populated.  Then, while I was waiting for an answer here, I did some refactoring on the database side, which resulted in an empty dataset.

When I fixed the db and set `myOptions` to only static values, it worked fine.